# Obtaining Doctrine entity meta data

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity, metadata

I'm trying to read the annotation meta data from a Doctrine entity for the purpose of instantiating a custom repository:

```
$userRepository = new \My\Repository\UserRepository( $entityManager, $classMetadata );
```

To obtain the `$classMetadata` I have the following:

My `User` entity:

```
namespace My\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId( $id )
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

My `UserRepository`:

```
namespace My\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository {

}
```

My main script:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array('../src/My/Entity');
$isDevMode = TRUE;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'dbname'   => 'mydb',
    'user'     => 'myuser',
    'password' => 's3cr3t',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

$classMetadata = $entityManager->getClassMetadata('\My\Entity\User');
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class "My\Entity\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.' in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:216
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried the following:

```
$userRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('\My\Entity\User');
```

But I'm getting the same error.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have set up the `bootstrap.php` and `cli-config.php` file as described in the Doctrine tutorials [1] and I can now run the `bin/doctrine` command line utilities. Interesting results:

```
bin/doctrine orm:validate-schema
```

Output:

```
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.
```

But when I do:

```
bin/doctrine orm:info
```

Output:

```
[Exception]                                                                                                                                                                             
You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have entities or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.
```

Any ideas?

[1] http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out eventually. I answered in a different question with a related issue:

[No mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058689/no-mapped-doctrine-orm-entities-according-to-the-current-configuration)