# No mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I've got a dubious issue. I have a set of existing annotated Doctrine entities which have been successfully used in a Symfony2/Doctrine2 project. However, I'm currently isolating some core functionality of this project into it's own web framework independent library and I can't seem to get the entities to function properly.

At the moment my major concern is the fact that the Doctrine CLI utility is giving me mixed results.

When I do the following:

```
bin/doctrine orm:validate-schema
```

I get the following output:

```
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.
```

But when I do:

```
bin/doctrine orm:info
```

I get this:

```
[Exception]                                                                                                                                                                             
You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have entities or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.
```

I have gone over my configuration a gazillion times now. I've even removed all my entities and left a most basic User entity in there giving me the same scenario.

What could possible be the source of these mixed results?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out that the standard Doctrine config set up [1] doesn't work with my code base, or any code base I have tested with, maybe the docs are outdated. After ploughing through the Interwebs for hours, this is the configuration that finally made it work for me:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

$paths = array( realpath(__DIR__."/../src/My/Entity") );
$isDevMode = TRUE;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'myuser',
    'password' => 's3cr3t',
    'dbname'   => 'mydb',
);

$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();

$reader = new AnnotationReader();
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver($reader, $paths);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl( $cache );
$config->setQueryCacheImpl( $cache );
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl( $driver );

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

//-- This I had to add to support the Mysql enum type.
$platform = $entityManager->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

[1] http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Comment: Many thanks for this fix! Do you have any other explaination for it?
In my case I didn't have to specify a particular cache, just the reader.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was the `AnnotationReader`. Also, as in my Symfony 2 Doctrine config, I had to explicitly add the `enum` type `string` to the type mapping.

Comment: If this is the configuration, what file does it go into?

Comment: @JD A typical place would be the Doctrine Console [1]. If you're using a framework such as Silex or Slim however, then what you see above is typical configuration. [1] http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is ok but the same thing could be achieved in less verbose manner:

```js
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array( realpath(__DIR__."/../src/My/Entity") );
$isDevMode = TRUE;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'myuser',
    'password' => 's3cr3t',
    'dbname'   => 'mydb',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(
    $paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false
);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache());
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

//-- This I had to add to support the Mysql enum type.
$platform = $entityManager->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

All here is about usage of simple annotation driver or not (last parameter of the Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration function. By default, a simple annotation driver is used which doesn't recognise the **@ORM\Entity** annotation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification as to why the solution works!

Answer (score 4):

I have PHP entity in `Ressources/config/doctrine/Foo.orm.php`
but I use annotation.

Too different way for `orm = [Exception]`

You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have entities or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.

Just delete the bad entity file

Comment: In my case I used Symfony entity example, with Silex, and cause was @ORM/Entity it should be @Entity.

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened that I imported the vendor directory from a different system and it wasn't working properly.

A simple `composer install` or `php composer.phar install` fixed it.