# ORM No mapping information to process

Tags: orm, doctrine, migration

Sorry if this is a duplicate question cause I can't seem to find where the problem is in my code.

Once I run the code in the terminal `php vendor/bin/doctrine-migrations migrations:diff` I get the following error

[image: screenshot of the error]

I don't know where this error is coming from.

Update

When i run `php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:info` i get the following output in terminal

`! [CAUTION] You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration.

 ! If you have entities or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.`

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update

I was missing 2 lines of code in mijn config and those are followed.

`$platform = $entityManager->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');`

added these 2 lines and now i don't get any mapping problems.

Ow and used the following link [No mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058689/no-mapped-doctrine-orm-entities-according-to-the-current-configuration) This stack issue will explain what you need to do when you get this problem

UPDATE 
Found out that i was using @ORM/Entity and when i changed it to @Entity it worked. I went a bit deeper in to this and found out that "useSimpleAnnotationReader" is true so if you put that to false and removed the last 2 rows of code it works perfectly fine. it looks something like this now

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(
$paths,
$isDevMode,
null,
null,
false);
```

The last one is for "useSimpleAnnotationReader" i put this in the bootstrap.php

Cheers!

Comment: Setting `useSimpleAnnotationReader` to `false` was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me problem was that I had not added

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
```

above entities.